# Collapsing a Bootstrap 5 collapse by default on certain screen sizes

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I have a `card-body` that I wish to have open by default on large screen sizes, but closed by default on smaller screen sizes. However, it can be toggled open or closed at *any* screen size.

Currently, I have it collapsed by default. Here is a minimal example:

```
<div class="card border-primary map-layer">
    <h4 class="card-header bg-primary text-white">
        Header
        <span class="float-end">
            <a class="btn btn-light btn-sm" data-bs-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseMenu" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseMenu"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></a>
        </span>
    </h4>
    <div class="collapse" id="collapseMenu">
        <div class="card-body">
            Some text here
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am using Bootstrap 5.2.1. Using `.d-lg-block` etc does not work, as this does the animation for collapsing, but leaves the `card-body` visible, nor does adding in a media selector for `display: none`, which then never shows the body.

I've trawled through the Bootstrap documentation, and online and have found many examples of displaying or collapsing elements at various sizes - but none of these then seem to allow the user to have the option any any screen size.

Any help would be appreciated.